# How to multi index Date + Time when importing csv file

Tags: pandas

this is my code which has a txt file loaded into the new data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
desired_width = 320
pd.set_option('display.width', desired_width)
from datetime import datetime
print(new.head(5))
new.info()
```

and this is the result:

```
       Date         Time    Open
0  2013/1/4   07:00:00.0  7847.5
1  2013/1/4   07:00:00.1  7847.5
2  2013/1/4   07:00:00.2  7847.5
3  2013/1/4   07:00:00.3  7847.5
4  2013/1/4   07:00:00.4  7847.5
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 17 entries, 0 to 16
Data columns (total 3 columns):
Date     17 non-null object
 Time    17 non-null object
 Open    17 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1), object(2)
memory usage: 488.0+ bytes
```

I am failing to make the Date+Time as the index as both Date and Time are objects. also I need to keep the time with it's milliseconds.

Trails with:

```
pd.to_datetime(new.Date + ' ' + new.Time)
```

caused:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Time'
```

Please advice how to create the multiindex which will be as an float64 as other columns

thanks

Comment: pd.to_datetime(new.Date + ' ' + new.Time) should work, and works for me. It seems like you might have a space in the name, so it is the colname is " Time" not "Time".

Comment: So to set it as index, just have new.index = pd.to_datetime(new.Date + ' ' + new.Time). Note: This is not a multiindex, do you actually want a multiindex?

Comment: it was " Time" as you thought. df.columns = df.columns.str.strip() - this solved this. also, is there a way to turn the data from object to int64?

Comment: pd.to_numeric(new['Date']) or new['Date'].astype('int'), but are you sure you want this and not a datetime type? You can do operations on the datetime type.

Comment: how would i change them from object to datetime type?

Comment: pd.to_datetime(new.Date + ' ' + new.Time)

Answer (score 0):

`df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()` cuts all spaces from headers names and that datetime() works with no problem